# .html files not accessible in Magento when added to root folder

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

I'm running a Magento site and needed to upload a google site ownership confirmation file to the root. When I did this, html file was not accessible via url when typed as follows www.website.com/google0564e497cc4446t6.html instead I got a 404 page. Other file formats work just fine. I concluded that there must be a .htaccess redirect.

This is the .htaccess content:

```
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
##  RewriteRule ^(.)ItemDesc.asp?IC=(.)$ $1$2 [L]
##  RewriteRule ^supply-items/$ ItemDesc.asp?IC= [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /ItemDesc.asp?IC=$1 [L]
##RewriteRule ^ItemDesc.asp?IC=$ supply-items/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule test_rewrite\.html http://www.website.com/rewrite_successful.html [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

As it turns out the previous website redirects are very important for maintaining of SEO, so I cannot just remove them. However, is there a way to make an exception to specific .html files such as www.website.com/google0564e497cc4446t6.html using the .htaccess file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the first part of your rule and add a condition to skip the google file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/google(.*)\.html$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /ItemDesc.asp?IC=$1 [L]
```